# How to build widgets from any .ui files created by QtDesigner

Tags: qt, qt-creator, qt5, qt-designer

I would like to make something like GUI creator which takes an ui file and creates widgets in it, and show in a window. 
So I have created a button on click I use QFileDialog to get a file. 
And then I would like to use the ui file from QFileDialog to create that gui/widgets and show in a window.

I have tried QFormbuilder, but it always gives me compile error “undefined reference to `QFormBuilder::QFormBuilder()’”

Is there a way to do it in qt5?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 0):

From documentation of QUiLoader:

```
 QUiLoader loader;
 QFile file(":/forms/myform.ui");
 file.open(QFile::ReadOnly);
 QWidget *myWidget = loader.load(&file, this);
 file.close();
```

Comment: Hi, thanks. I have solved it. I was missing Formbuilder/UiLoader in my pro file. I have add them, and it is working.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the problem. 
Actually I was missing QFormbuilder module in my .pro file. So I have just added them, and it is working fine.